# Regex to exclude content between title tag

Tags: php, regex

What's wrong with this regex to exclude content of title tag?

```
$plaintext = preg_match('#<title>(.*?)</title>#', $html);
```

$html has html code of entire page.

Comment: looks like php i think

Comment: your question is unclear.Do you want to exclude title tag or it's content..And if it's the second case what would you want the output to be like!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you never got a working answer. Let's remove the title tags.

Search: `(?s)<title>.*?</title>`

Replace: `""`

Code:

```
$regex = "~(?s)<title>.*?</title>~";
$ replaced = preg_replace($regex,"",$pagecontent);
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?s)                     # set flags for this block (with . matching
                         # \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                         # matching normally) (matching whitespace
                         # and # normally)
<title>                  # '<title>'
.*?                      # any character (0 or more times (matching
                         # the least amount possible))
</title>                 # '</title>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be like this instead...**This only gives you content in between**

`preg_match('(?<=<title>).*(?=<\/title>)', $html);`

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1SJ

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: this does not exclude the content between <title>

Comment: then this is wrong function, you mean to remove it right. You need to use function that replaces the text with empty space and this regex.

Answer (score 0):

This will get everything between the two  tags

```
preg_match('<title>.+', $html);
```

Comment: @cyclic what do you mean by exclude? You want to get all the html data except for <title> tags?

Comment: If you want you can replace that info with "" the empty string then continue to parse the code.